# Excel Pivot table format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have the following in a excel pivot table

```
            Summer15 Fall15 Winter16 Spring16 Summer16 Fall16 Winter17  Sum
 a   pro1    0        0                  0        0       0        0     0
 a   pro1                        1                                       1
 b   pro2     0                                                          0
 b   pro2              1                                                  1
 b   pro2                                 2                               2
 b   pro2                        3                         3        6     12
 b   pro2                                          4                      4
```

where pro is a Row, seson in column and value is a value

I would like to get the following format instead:

```
            Summer15 Fall15 Winter16 Spring16 Summer16 Fall16 Winter17  Sum
 a   pro1    0        0         1        0        0       0        0     1
 b   pro2    0        1         3        2        4       3        6     19
```

Comment: Do you only have the "Pro" field under the "Row labels" section? Looks like you might have both the "Pro" field as well as the value field under Row labels.

Comment: I  have other variables in the row labels, but I double checked to see that value was not under row labels.

Comment: check your data source, if you don't have several versions of proX (with one or more trailing space). You can select in the pivot table the different pros and press F2 to make a quick check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your data organized in the table? It worked just fine for me, if the data is organized as I put in the image in example. The `Row Labels` is the Pro column, the `Column Labels` is the Season column and the `Values` is the Value column. Also, double check the spelling of proX, because if you have spaces in the strings, then you have different strings. If that is the case, you can use the `TRIM` function to adjust your strings.

[image: example]